# MEAN Stack app - Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, angular, mean-stack

I'm basically trying to create a register page using MEAN and I want to check against the database (Mongo using Mongoose) if the user and email already exists, if one of them is true, send a res.json fail.

And if the username and email are not already in the database, continue to add the user.

I'm getting an error "Can't set headers after they are sent." On the Node console and I'm trying to figure out why.

Once User.getUsername() returns a user in the callback (if the username passed exists in the db), shouldn't it return the json and end the request there? Why is it continuing to the User.adduser() function and trying to set the header there too?

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```
router.post('/register', (req, res, next) =>{
    let newUser = new User({ // Collect body info
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    });

    // Check if username is available
    User.getUserByUsername(newUser.username, (err, user) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        if(user){ 
            return res.json({success: false, msg: 'User already exists'});
            // I want to end here if there's a user
        }
    });

    //Continue to add user if getUserByUsername() returns false for user

    // Add user
    User.addUser(newUser, (err, user) => { // Add user
        if(err){
            return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Failed to register'});
        } else {
            return res.json({success: true, msg: 'You have been successfully registered!'});
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic you have doesn't work for as expected because of how asynchronous methods work. The current logic is do `User.getUserByUsername` then do `User.addUser` and if either method calls back, handle it. I'm pretty sure you want, do `User.getUserByUsername`, wait for it's callback, then call `User.addUser` if necessary. Here's a crude implementation, you could use promises or define the methods outside of the logic to clean it up. Also, make sure you are calling res.end() at some point in your code.

```
router.post('/register', (req, res, next) =>{
    let newUser = new User({ // Collect body info
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    });

    // Check if username is available
    User.getUserByUsername(newUser.username, (err, user) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        if(user){ 
            return res.json({success: false, msg: 'User already exists'});
            // I want to end here if there's a user
        }else{
            //Continue to add user if getUserByUsername() returns false for user

            // Add user
            User.addUser(newUser, (err, user) => { // Add user
                if(err){
                    return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Failed to register'});
                } else {
                    return res.json({success: true, msg: 'You have been successfully registered!'});
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yep this is how I thought of implementing it. However, I thought it would be extremely messy once I add the checKIfEmailExists() method as well.  I have it working now, it checks the uniqueness of the username, inside the callback, it checks the email and inside the check email callback, if both username and email are good it adds the user. It works but it's very messy and un-readable